# jQuery - How to get position of element that has a class

Tags: jquery, css

I have an slider that ads an class (.current-item) to each tab that is on, and removes when it`s off.
I want to use LavaLamp for the menu efect and I need to get the position of the each element that has class current-item.

I used:

```
var my = $("li.current-item");

var myposition = my.position();

function setCurr(el) {

        $back.css({'top': myposition.top });

        curr = el;

};
```

But it works only for one item (the first). 
Afer the slider removes the class and ads the class to the next li nothing happens.

Here it is live: **http://asgg.ro/slider-html/**
The src to the script is at the bottom of the source.

I`m new to jquery and I really need some help!
Thank you very much

Comment: Where did you put that code? You have to find ".current-item" every time you want to check the position - try putting those first two lines *inside* your "setCurr" function.

Comment: @Pointy has the answer I think.  Depends on the code you left out. But it does look like you need to re-find the position of .current-item in the setCurr function

Comment: Thank you for answers, but not working. This is the live version http://asgg.ro/slider-html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var offset = $('.class_name').offset();

var x_pos = offset.left;
var y_pos = offset.top;
```

this will give you the X and Y position of the element related to the viewport
Hoper this helps

Comment: Four spaces before a line formats as code. `ctr-k` puts 4 spaces before each line in a selection.

Comment: sorry Peter, I just have forgotten to format the message, thank you for editing it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function setCurr(el) {
    var my = $("li.current-item");
    var myposition = my.position();
    $back.css({'top': myposition.top });
    curr = el;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it`s not working. I tried a lot of combinations. This is the live version: http://asgg.ro/slider-html/